# why 'unset http_proxy' doesn't work in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line, rakefile

**'unset http_proxy' or 'unset HTTP_PROXY' doesnt work in the Rakefile with following two scenerios where other bash commands work succesfully**

*file format : Rakefile

**Scenerio 1:**

```
 desc "Remove HTTP  Proxy"
 task :remove_http do

 puts "removing HTTP  Proxy..."
 sh "unset HTTP_PROXY"
 puts"Removed HTTP & HTTPS Porxy"
 puts "Showing Environment Variables"
 sh "env"

end
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
 desc "Remove HTTP Proxy"
 task :remove_http do

 puts "removing HTTP Proxy..."
`unset HTTP_PROXY`
 puts"Removed HTTP Porxy"
 puts "Showing Environment Variables"
 sh "env"

end
```

Any Idea how to solve or that bash command for unsetting HTTP_PROXY will be succesfull in ruby Rakefile ?

Comment: When you run "sh env" you're launching a different shell than the one that Rake is running in.  They're two different processes with different environments.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate what Joe mentioned,

when you execute something with sh, your launching a different shell/session than what your ruby program is running in.

In this case, you `unset HTTP_PROXY` in a session.
Then you show the environment in a different session.
And there is a third session which is running your ruby program.

If you want to unset HTTP_PROXY,
Try doing this

```
p ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] # See if it's there
ENV.delete('HTTP_PROXY')
p ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] # See if it's gone
```

Comment: p ENV['HTTPPROXY']  # i can see what is proxy variable

Comment: ENV.delete('HTTP_PROXY') # this command doesnt work in this case and dont know why actually

Comment: Ooopss, I definitely typoed my answer. Make sure the variable matches!

Comment: i have tried several ways and as you written but unfortunatly it doesnt... :(